# JS trivia - defining function inside if condition

Tags: javascript

Why does this code print `undefined` instead of `function`:

```
if (function f(){}) {
    console.log(typeof f);
}
```

...while this one prints `function` as expected:

```
eval('function g(){}');
console.log(typeof g);
```

(And also `if (x = 42) console.log(x);` prints `42` as expected.)

**NOTE:** I am perfectly aware that this kind of code is bad practice, and I know that most linters would also reject it, as they should... but I'm just *curious* what is the logic behind Javascript's interpreter's behavior.

Comment: I *think* because you define an anonymous function (because you wrapped it in `()`), the function `f` only exists inside those `()`.

Comment: The major difference is that `f()` is defined in an expression and `g()` is defined as a statement.

Comment: Try `if (f = function() {})` and see what happens. This may give you some additional insight. See [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Function_constructor_vs._function_declaration_vs._function_expression)

Comment: @JeffHuijsmans The parentheses are part of the if statement syntax, they don't create a scope.

Comment: @JJJ thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the name of the function in a named function expression is not added to the scope where the expression occurs (unlike a function *declaration*, where the name *is* added to the scope where it occurs). With an NFE, the name is only in scope within the function. The one in your `if` is an NFE. The one in your `eval` is a declaration.

Examples:

```js
// NFE
var x = function foo() {
  console.log("2: ", typeof foo); // function
};
console.log("1: ", typeof foo);   // undefined
x();

// Declaration
function bar() {
}
console.log("3: ", typeof bar);   // function
```

When the `function` production is being used as a value (e.g., in the `if`, or on the right-hand side of an assignment, etc.), it's an expression. When it's standalone, it's a declaration.

Comment: aaah, I totally missed the "function declaration" vs. "function expression" in play here... thanks for clearing it up!